# Where is my wpa_supplicant.conf?

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I am trying to locate the wpa_supplicant.conf on Ubuntu 14.04 with no  luck. I tried to `locate` but I couldn't find it. the `locate` command gives the following output:

```
~$ sudo locate wpa_supplicant.conf  
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/wpa_supplicant.conf 
/home/pervysage/wpa_supplicant.conf
/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/wpa_supplicant.conf.5.gz
```

I am connected to my Wi-Fi so there must be a wpa_supplicant.conf file present, right? If so, why am I unable to locate it?

Comment: After years of fighting it for simple network connections, I'd honestly recommend just letting Network Manager handle things these days (especially when it comes down to wireless security).

Comment: I'm just seeing (and want to play with) the WiFi source code and want to give the computer my own wpa_supplicant. I want to backup the original just in case something messes up.

Answer (score 8):

If you use NetworkManager to configure your wifi connections look in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

There should be files in there for all your configured network connections.

Comment: But where's `wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Comment: If you use NetworkManager it looks after wireless settings for you. It doesn't create a wpa_supplicant.conf file with all the network settings in it. It stores connection settings in a bunch of connection files.

Answer (score 1):

`wpa_supplicant` doesn't run with a conf. It's a daemon that communicates with your network manager using DBUS. You can see what's happening with `wpa_cli` which will show you the instructions being received by the daemon.

That's not to say you can not run with a configuration file, you can. But, Ubuntu doesn't use that configuration file at all. It's all remotely controlled through the DBUS api.

Answer (score 0):

The *specific* answer to the question "***Where is my wpa_supplicant.conf?***" is as follows:

### Method 1:

Copy a specimen file from ***/usr/share/doc/*** to ***/etc***  as per README instructions in line 262 in ***/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/README.Debian.gz*** :

```
# copy the template to /etc/wpa_supplicant/
cp /usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/examples/wpa-roam.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

# allow only root to read and write to file
chmod 0600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I found the ***README*** file- and the specimen files to create a ***wpa_supplicant.conf*** - with:

```
dpkg -L wpasupplicant
```

Above answer produced from an ***Ubuntu 18.04*** system.

### Method 2

Put the following into a script, edit the directives with values specific to your setup, *chmod 700* the file and execute it.  It's minimal, but should suit most use cases. This should do all the related grunt work to get your ***wpa_supplicant*** configured.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB
ap_scan=1

network={
        ssid="SSIDNAME"
        psk="AP-WPA2-PASSWD-GOES-HERE"
}
EOF

chmod 0600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

usermod -G netdev -a pi

systemctl unmask wpa_supplicant.service
systemctl enable wpa_supplicant.service
systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service
```

Hope this helps you