# Boot error: wpa_supplicant dbus_property=? on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi, wpa-supplicant

My system boots fine and Network Manager kicks in when I log in and my wifi connects, but I get the following boot errors in my journalctl -b

```
wpa_supplicant[6756]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=
wpa_supplicant[6756]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
wpa_supplicant[6756]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
wpa_supplicant[6756]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=
```

I guess it doesn't like the fact that my dbus_property is blank?

**Is there a way to prevent these boot errors?** Can I fix the missing dbus_property? Or is there a way to keep dbus from loading wpa_supplicant without breaking my network connection?

Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Kernel driver & modules in use: iwlwifi

Useful links:
[Where is my wpa_supplicant.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497540/where-is-my-wpa-supplicant-conf)
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/wpa_supplicant.conf.5.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WPAHowTo

**EDIT:**
Looks like this is an old bug without a solution or work-around: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1439771

None of these suggestions worked: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306276/make-systemd-stop-starting-unwanted-wpa-supplicant-service

Comment: Looks like uninstalling wpasupplicant isn't an option, because it'll also remove Network Manager and Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The package `wpa_supplicant` provides client support for WPA and WPA2 encryption. If you expect that your wireless will successfully authenticate with a wireless access point, usually a router, that uses WPA and/or WPA2, then it is required to be installed and running.

> My system boots fine and Network Manager kicks in

I assume that your wireless then connects perfectly well.

```
wpa_supplicant[6756]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=
wpa_supplicant[6756]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
wpa_supplicant[6756]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
wpa_supplicant[6756]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=
```

We see no error there, nor even any warnings. I suspect that these are informational messages only.

In any event, if your system boots normally and the wireless connects normally, as it apparently does, there is nothing to fix.

Comment: The second and third lines of that message are in red, bold font. I thought that signified an error, no?

Comment: Correct; however, there is no evidence that dbus hasn't corrected or recovered from the error as wpa_supplicant and wireless are working as expected.

Comment: I noticed that people typically have the dbus_property set equal to Stations. Is there an easy way to set that, or is it better to take a "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" approach?

Comment: In my opinion, the latter. Your system boots, the wireless connects and, unless you dig deep in the logs looking for something to "fix", all is working as expected.